# Can I edit colors of external svg file using fetch and xml dom?

Tags: reactjs, xml, svg, dom, fetch

What I want to do is to first fetch the external svg file, and then load it as an XML DOM. I then want to be able to edit the stroke colors and fills of the svg. However, what I have doesn't seem to be working:

```
const defaultSymbolFiles = import.meta.glob('/public/presets_library/symbol_presets/*.svg')
const defaultSymbolFileNames = Object.keys(defaultSymbolFiles)

const defaultSymbolColors = [
  'darkorchid',
  'magenta',
  'darkred',
  '#ff5b5b',
  'darkorange',
  'darkgoldenrod',
  '#13be00',
  'darkgreen',
  'darkcyan',
  'darkturquoise',
  'cornflowerblue',
  'darkblue',
  '#641d6d',
  'saddlebrown',
  'black',
  'dimgray',
]

const combosArr = [...defaultSymbolFileNames].map((file, index) => {
  return {
    symbol: file,
    color: defaultSymbolColors[index]
  }
})

    for (let symbolComboIndex = 0; symbolComboIndex < combosArr; symbolComboIndex++) {
      console.log('combosArr', combosArr)
      const xml = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // fetching the symbol using the path
        fetch(combosArr[symbolComboIndex]['symbol'])
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
      .then(data => svgRef.current.innerHTML = data)
      .then(data => new DOMParser().parseFromString( data, 'image/svg+xml'))
      .then(body => body.text())
    }
```

I feel that I might have something missing from this. If I do, please let me know. Thanks!